# Optimization: Storing ISO 639-3 language in a MySQL column (int language_id or varchar language)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, iso-639

I have a MySQL DB that needs to be fast at scale.

**Option 1**
Tables can store the language ISO 639-3 code as a column: varchar(3) language

**Option 2**
Tables can store the ID for the language as a column: int(2?) language_id, and there can be a languages table with the ISO 639-3 code.

**Question**
What makes sense for speed at scale? Option 1 is easier to read in the DB. I'd prefer it if speed is the same or completely negligible even at scale.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
    ISO_630_3 CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

That will be 3 bytes, which is smaller than `INT` (4 bytes)`and not much bigger than`SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes).

(Am I correct in saying that the codes are always 3 ascii letters?  Hence no need for `VAR`, which takes an extra byte or two.)

`CHAR(3)` is readily indexable.  There is no significant advantage in 'normalizing' even to smallint.  This still applies even at the scale of a billion rows.

And, as you point out, "easier to read" is worth something.

If you are also storing text, I assume that all such text can be mapped to UTF-8?  If so, use

```
     my_text TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

In MySQL, there is no problem having different columns in a single table using different charsets (or collations).

Perhaps worth noting...  Many languages can be discovered from the hex utf-8 encoding:

```
⚈  Cxyy -- More Western Europe: Latin (C3-CA), Combining Diacritical Marks (CC-CD), Greek (CE-CF)
⚈  Dxyy -- Cyrillic (D0-D4), Hebrew (D6-D7), Arabic/Persian/Farsi (D8-DB), etc
⚈  E0yyyy -- various Indian character sets, southern Asia, etc.
⚈  E1yyyy -- Cherokee, Balinese, Khmer, Mongolian, Vietnamese, etc.
(etc)
```

-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#diagnosing_charset_issues